# How do I plot Pandas Dataframe columns on separate figures?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am try to take a Pandas dataframe which has 57 columns and plot them on a bar chart with 3 columns per figure. The reason is that the variation in the data and the length of the columns makes is hard to see the data in many of the plots. Plotting multiple columns per subplot isn't an option so each plot has to be visible at the output size. Given the data I have found that 3 subplots per figure looks the best. Here's my script to plot the dataframe:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df.columns), ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
yscale = np.ceil(df.abs().select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).values.max())
plt.yscale('symlog')
plt.ylim(-yscale, yscale)
t = list(df.columns.values)
n = 0
for i in df:
    df['positive'] = df[i] > 0
    df[i].plot.bar(ax=ax[n], rot=0, width=1.0, legend=False, position=0, color=df.positive.map({True: 'g', False: 'r'}))
    ax[n].set_title(t[n])
    ax[n].axhline(y=0, linewidth=1, color='k')
    ax[n].tick_params(which='major', axis='x', length=2)
    ax[n].tick_params(which='major', axis='y', length=6)
    n += 1
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Would it be easiest just to split the dataframe into several smaller dataframes? My only concern with that is that there will be different numbers of columns per dataframe with different samples.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want 19 subplots, each with 3 columns in barchart?

Comment: No I want to plot 19 separate figures with 3 subplots per figure. The value in the columns is being plotted as the values along the bar chart. So each column would have its own bar chart. I didn't know if there was a way to plot multiple figures in addition to having multiple subplots per figure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you want

```
for i in range(19):
    df.iloc[:,i*3:i*3+3].plot.bar(subplots=True,
                                  legend=None)
```

which gives 19 plots similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I can't believe I didn't think of that.